# $x = -y^3/8$ and $ y= -2x^3$ Systems of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Algebra has been a while and I forgot how to do this.

Say we have the following 2 properties, how would we be able to use the system of equations?

$x = -y^3/8$ and $ y= -2x^3$

The result is supposed to be $(0,0), (-1, 2), (1, -2)$ but I'm not getting there when I try to substitute.

Comment: "I'm not getting there when I try to substitute.": what ??

Comment: When I try to substitute them into each other (thats how you do it if I remember correctly), I'm not getting to the values (the real answer) @yves

Comment: Do you claim that the given solutions are not solutions ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sub the value of $y$ from $ii$ in $i$ or the value of $x$ from $i$ in $ii$

I'm doing in the 1st way.

$\begin{align}&x = -\frac{y^3}{8} = -\frac{(-2x^3)^3}{8} = x^9 \\
\Rightarrow &x^9 - x = x(x^8-1) = x(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1) = 0\end{align}$

**If you need only real values**, then $x = 0,-1,1$ and correspondingly, $y = 0, 2,-2$